# Android Games specifically bitmaps

Tags: android

I'm building an android game and this is more of just best practices and performance question.

For the bitmaps that I have that the user interacts with, should I place them in an imageView and set an onTouchListener for each of them individually or should I just draw them onto the canvas and use the custom view's onTouch method to obtain the x and y of the touch and see if it falls in the range of any of the bitmaps to detect a touch.

My custom view takes up the entire screen, and I don't know how if it is even possible to draw an imageview onto the screen using a canvas which is why as of now I just use the onTouch method.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how dynamic your bitmaps render will be, you should go for either GLSurfaceView or SurfaceView, for something simple as just bitmaps i would recommend you to use SurfaceView as "renderer" where you can get the canvas from and of course you can draw on the whole screen if your surfaceview match the screen size.

TouchListener should be completely separated handled on its own listener promoting encapsulation and reuse of code for future apps that you want to do. I've found this quiet helpful for the last games i've developed asingning a surface view as renderer and just creating Objects which takes the canvas as parameter and drawing them self into it, the only thing you have to take on count is the bitmap resource management, but if you are careful of releasing and creating them when is proper, you should have no problems...

Regards!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do use a surfaceView for rending the graphics. It does take up the entire screen and i do draw all of my bitmaps using the canvas.drawBitmap method. I was just wondering if this is the way to do it. Or have the surfaceView take up lets say 2/3 of the screen and then below it have a relativelayout or something where i can implement an imageview and create listeners for each image. But i dont think that is correct.

Comment: There's a good in performance trick to do this, you can only get X and Y position from Listener, and keep track of your bitmaps drawn as Rects, you can make use of "contains" method in rect, to know if the events are inside that bitmaps rectangle, is simple and performance friendly...

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. So that is the correct way to do it then? Draw the bitmaps and then implement the onTouch method from view and get the X and Y and then check the x and y if they are in the bounds of the image and that would indicate if it has been touched. Not create imageviews for each bitmap and set individual onTouchListeners for each imageViews?

Comment: Definitely, take on count the scalability you want to give to your game, getting 1 images view per object in your game is extremly expensive in performance, ImageView comes well suited with a whole bunch of functionality that you dont even care, and truth is that when it comes to games, you have to do the more with the less...

Comment: I guess i have another question. Are most android games built like that. The actually gameplay is in a custom view that extends a surface view and all of the objects are specifically draw to the screen using the canvas?

Comment: It depends, on the rendering power that your game needs, if its really complex chances is that you need to go for OpenGL, but for a not 3D/hard rendering game, SurfaceView is perfect...

Comment: But the custom game view takes up the entire screen? there aren't complex hierarchies of layouts and other views in the actual gameplay screen are there?

Comment: Usually we try to avoid that as much as we can, because long layout hierarchies have a huge impact in screen updates, so if you think you'll see a Layout with a bunch of objects inside, thats not what good architectured games does, they use the surface view plenty as a canvas that gets updated as if it was a video...

Comment: what if you like divide the screen up though. Sorry for all of these "what if" but im trying to learn as much as i can about android programming. So if your screen is 2/3 your custom view which renders all of the game graphics and the botton third is a lets say relative layout with like game control features. That bottom third wouldn't continuously get updated in the game thread loop so shouldn't that be ok?

Comment: Thats usually what i do, i keep a small layout and as simple as possible below the actual rendering, for controlling purposes, usually this elements just expose variables used to control the game workflow...

Comment: hmm i wonder if that is what i should do. i have a game where a figure is moved left or right. As of now these movements are controlled by two buttons. These buttons though exist in the surfaceview and are draw on throughout every game loop iteration. Maybe i should break the screen up then

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33392/discussion-between-cbaker-and-martin-cazares)